# R2016b problems - CELL2MAT does not support cell arrays containing cell arrays or objects

Tags: matlab

First, I've placed some stock data at this link

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9hoshsWoDHGOGs1SGFDTG9BYlk

which is loaded by the 1st line in the code snippet to demonstrate the problem.

The code, which works in R2016a and earlier, but fails in R2016b, is here:

```
FileName = '~/TestFile.csv';

tmpData = readtable(FileName);
Data = tmpData(:,3:size(tmpData, 2));
names = fieldnames(Data);

DataArray=table2array(Data);

DateCell = table2cell(tmpData(:,1));

count = size(Data, 2);

for i=1:count
    tmpStr = char(names(i));
%        fprintf('%s\n', tmpStr);
    TS(i) = timeseries(DataArray(:,i), DateCell, 'Name', tmpStr);
end
```

In R2016b the DateCell variable appears to be a 1091 cell array filed with '1x1 datetime' elements causing the call to timeseries to fail. In all earlier versions of Matlab it appears to be a 1091 cell array filled with dates which worked correctly in timeseries.

So, assuming someone with better skills can verify as much, what's the coding change to fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get back the R2016a and prior behaviour by adding the `'DatetimeType'` argument to `readtable`, like so:

```
tmpData = readtable(FileName, 'DatetimeType', 'text')
```

This incompatibility is mentioned in the [release notes](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/release-notes.html?rntext=readtable&startrelease=R2016b&endrelease=R2016b&rntype=incompatibility&groupby=release&sortby=descending&searchHighlight=readtable).